# Risks of upgrading VC2019 projects from C++14 to C++17

Tags: c++

We have a legacy system that contains around 30 VC++ projects that are currently set to C++14. To support a new requirement we have had to update one of the projects, a library project shared across most of the others, to C++17.

I'm aware of the VC++ 2017-2019 upgrade docs, but what about the language change itself from C++14 to C++17? If all 30 projects build would we be safe to assume the update is fine? We don't have extensive automated tests due to the age of the code and its recent introduction to the company.

Also, if the included library (*.lib) is C++17 does that have any impact on the runtime of applications including it that are still C++14?

Comment: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html has a list oh removals, new features, and modifications

Comment: Also, possibly upgrading will find hidden bugs that existed in your codebase.   If the program running in C++17 breaks, it may not have anything to do with C++17 itself, but bugs that have now been exposed.  Just be prepared for that scenario.

Comment: Make sure you have unit test and that you can run a test build with c++17 enabled. Doing such a build with smokes should give you actual info for your risk assessment.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have a suite of tests (working on it!) and this needs to be released before we do, hence the question on risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary doesn't care what was the syntax of the original text from which it was created. If you're using a binary .lib file in all your other projects - it doesn't matter if it was compiled in C++14 or C++17 mode to them. So in that regard there's no dependency.

So you should be able to change the settings of only the relevant project, not all of them, that could reduce your scope significantly for regression testing.

Comment: Even if compiled under the same compiler, couldn't there be issues with ABI compatibility when compiling part of a program on a different version?

Comment: That's what the regression testing is for, right? My point is that the syntax changes may not be needed in all the 30 projects, just the one affected. If the syntax changes don't affect the external header files, the chances for ABI compatibility issues are low (although non-zero, of course)